# Backprop implementation issue

Tags: python, matlab, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

What I am supposed to do. I have an black and white image (100x100px):

[image]

I am supposed to train a [backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) neural network with this image. The inputs are x, y coordinates of the image (from 0 to 99) and output is either 1 (white color) or 0 (black color).

Once the network has learned, I would like it to reproduce the image based on its weights and get the closest possible image to the original.

Here is my backprop implementation:

```
import os
import math
import Image
import random
from random import sample

#------------------------------ class definitions

class Weight:
    def __init__(self, fromNeuron, toNeuron):
        self.value = random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)
        self.fromNeuron = fromNeuron
        self.toNeuron = toNeuron
        fromNeuron.outputWeights.append(self)
        toNeuron.inputWeights.append(self)
        self.delta = 0.0 # delta value, this will accumulate and after each training cycle used to adjust the weight value

    def calculateDelta(self, network):
        self.delta += self.fromNeuron.value * self.toNeuron.error

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0.0        # the output
        self.idealValue = 0.0   # the ideal output
        self.error = 0.0        # error between output and ideal output
        self.inputWeights = []
        self.outputWeights = []

    def activate(self, network):
        x = 0.0;
        for weight in self.inputWeights:
            x += weight.value * weight.fromNeuron.value
        # sigmoid function
        if x < -320:
            self.value = 0
        elif x > 320:
            self.value = 1
        else:
            self.value = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, neurons):
        self.neurons = neurons

    def activate(self, network):
        for neuron in self.neurons:
            neuron.activate(network)

class Network:
    def __init__(self, layers, learningRate):
        self.layers = layers
        self.learningRate = learningRate # the rate at which the network learns
        self.weights = []
        for hiddenNeuron in self.layers[1].neurons:
            for inputNeuron in self.layers[0].neurons:
                self.weights.append(Weight(inputNeuron, hiddenNeuron))
            for outputNeuron in self.layers[2].neurons:
                self.weights.append(Weight(hiddenNeuron, outputNeuron))

    def setInputs(self, inputs):
        self.layers[0].neurons[0].value = float(inputs[0])
        self.layers[0].neurons[1].value = float(inputs[1])

    def setExpectedOutputs(self, expectedOutputs):
        self.layers[2].neurons[0].idealValue = expectedOutputs[0]

    def calculateOutputs(self, expectedOutputs):
        self.setExpectedOutputs(expectedOutputs)
        self.layers[1].activate(self) # activation function for hidden layer
        self.layers[2].activate(self) # activation function for output layer        

    def calculateOutputErrors(self):
        for neuron in self.layers[2].neurons:
            neuron.error = (neuron.idealValue - neuron.value) * neuron.value * (1 - neuron.value)

    def calculateHiddenErrors(self):
        for neuron in self.layers[1].neurons:
            error = 0.0
            for weight in neuron.outputWeights:
                error += weight.toNeuron.error * weight.value
            neuron.error = error * neuron.value * (1 - neuron.value)

    def calculateDeltas(self):
        for weight in self.weights:
            weight.calculateDelta(self)

    def train(self, inputs, expectedOutputs):
        self.setInputs(inputs)
        self.calculateOutputs(expectedOutputs)
        self.calculateOutputErrors()
        self.calculateHiddenErrors()
        self.calculateDeltas()

    def learn(self):
        for weight in self.weights:
            weight.value += self.learningRate * weight.delta

    def calculateSingleOutput(self, inputs):
        self.setInputs(inputs)
        self.layers[1].activate(self)
        self.layers[2].activate(self)
        #return round(self.layers[2].neurons[0].value, 0)
        return self.layers[2].neurons[0].value


#------------------------------ initialize objects etc

inputLayer = Layer([Neuron() for n in range(2)])
hiddenLayer = Layer([Neuron() for n in range(10)])
outputLayer = Layer([Neuron() for n in range(1)])

learningRate = 0.4

network = Network([inputLayer, hiddenLayer, outputLayer], learningRate)


# let's get the training set
os.chdir("D:/stuff")
image = Image.open("backprop-input.gif")
pixels = image.load()
bbox = image.getbbox()
width = 5#bbox[2] # image width
height = 5#bbox[3] # image height

trainingInputs = []
trainingOutputs = []
b = w = 0
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        if (0, 0, 0, 255) == pixels[x, y]:
            color = 0
            b += 1
        elif (255, 255, 255, 255) == pixels[x, y]:
            color = 1
            w += 1
        trainingInputs.append([float(x), float(y)])
        trainingOutputs.append([float(color)])

print "\nOriginal image ... Black:"+str(b)+" White:"+str(w)+"\n"

#------------------------------ let's train

for i in range(500):
    for j in range(len(trainingOutputs)):
        network.train(trainingInputs[j], trainingOutputs[j])
        network.learn()
    for w in network.weights:
        w.delta = 0.0

#------------------------------ let's check

b = w = 0
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        out = network.calculateSingleOutput([float(x), float(y)])
        if 0.0 == round(out):
            color = (0, 0, 0, 255)
            b += 1
        elif 1.0 == round(out):
            color = (255, 255, 255, 255)
            w += 1
        pixels[x, y] = color
        #print out

print "\nAfter learning the network thinks ... Black:"+str(b)+" White:"+str(w)+"\n"
```

Obviously, there is some issue with my implementation. The above code returns:

> Original image ... Black:21 White:4
>
> After learning the network thinks ...
>   Black:25 White:0

It does the same thing if I try to use larger training set (I'm testing just 25 pixels from the image above for testing purposes). It returns that all pixels should be black after learning.

Now, if I use a manual training set like this instead:

```
trainingInputs = [
    [0.0,0.0],
    [1.0,0.0],
    [2.0,0.0],
    [0.0,1.0],
    [1.0,1.0],
    [2.0,1.0],
    [0.0,2.0],
    [1.0,2.0],
    [2.0,2.0]
]
trainingOutputs = [
    [0.0],
    [1.0],
    [1.0],
    [0.0],
    [1.0],
    [0.0],
    [0.0],
    [0.0],
    [1.0]
]

#------------------------------ let's train

for i in range(500):
    for j in range(len(trainingOutputs)):
        network.train(trainingInputs[j], trainingOutputs[j])
        network.learn()
    for w in network.weights:
        w.delta = 0.0

#------------------------------ let's check

for inputs in trainingInputs:
    print network.calculateSingleOutput(inputs)
```

The output is for example:

```
0.0330125791296   # this should be 0, OK
0.953539182136    # this should be 1, OK
0.971854575477    # this should be 1, OK
0.00046146137467  # this should be 0, OK
0.896699762781    # this should be 1, OK
0.112909223162    # this should be 0, OK
0.00034058462280  # this should be 0, OK
0.0929886299643   # this should be 0, OK
0.940489647869    # this should be 1, OK
```

In other words the network guessed all pixels right (both black and white). Why does it say all pixels should be black if I use actual pixels from the image instead of hard coded training set like the above?

I tried changing the amount of neurons in the hidden layers (up to 100 neurons) with no success.

This is a homework.

This is also a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988238/help-me-with-my-backprop-implementation-in-python) about backprop.

Comment: Why did you tag this as MATLAB? It looks like you are only using Python.

Comment: @gnovice Well, I think that MATLAB is often used for programming neural networks and other AI stuff so I thought some MATLAB programmers might be able to spot an error in my algorithm even though it is written in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while, but I did get my degree in this stuff, so I think hopefully some of it has stuck.

From what I can tell, you're too deeply overloading your middle layer neurons with the input set.  That is, your input set consists of 10,000 discrete input values (100 pix x 100 pix); you're attempting to encode those 10,000 values into 10 neurons.  This level of encoding is hard (I suspect it's possible, but certainly hard); at the least, you'd need a LOT of training (more than 500 runs) to get it to reproduce reasonably.  Even with 100 neurons for the middle layer, you're looking at a relatively dense compression level going on (100 pixels to 1 neuron).

As to what to do about these problems; well, that's tricky.  You can increase your number of middle neurons dramatically, and you'll get a reasonable effect, but of course it'll take a long time to train.  However, I think there might be a different solution; if possible, you might consider using polar coordinates instead of cartesian coordinates for the input; quick eyeballing of the input pattern indicates a high level of symmetry, and effectively you'd be looking at a linear pattern with a repeated predictable deformation along the angular coordinate, which it seems would encode nicely in a small number of middle layer neurons.

This stuff is tricky; going for a general solution for pattern encoding (as your original solution does) is very complex, and can usually (even with large numbers of middle layer neurons) require a lot of training passes; on the other hand, some advance heuristic task breakdown and a little bit of problem redefinition (i.e. advance converting from cartesian to polar coordinates) can give good solutions **for well defined problem sets**.  Therein, of course, is the perpetual rub; general solutions are hard to come by, but slightly more specified solutions can be quite nice indeed.

Interesting stuff, in any event!

Comment: @Amro: thx, the symmetry lends itself to polar coordinates very clearly.

Comment: @McWafflestix: In solving machine learning problems, the most important thing is having useful features (preprocessing step), the algorithm considerations comes second to that (you can usually use some sort of cross-validation to find the best parameters for you model)

Comment: @McWafflestix Thanks for suggestions. I will try them out but it won't be until the weekend. I'm really busy atm.

Comment: @RichardKnop: no problem, glad to help.  Please update us with how things turn out!

Comment: @Amro: exactly.  The OP stated that the inputs were cartesian coordinates; that's why I was a little bit uncertain about the polar coordinates.  If the constraint on the problem is just that the inputs must be dual (i.e., either cartesian or polar coordinates), it would be a slamdunk for polar coordinates, since that linear transform most efficiently uses the features of the given input.