# taking log of very small values using numpy/scipy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I have an Nx1 array that corresponds to a probability distribution, i.e. the sum of the elements sums to 1.  This is represented as a regular numpy array.  Since N might be relatively large, e.g. 10 or 20, many of the individual elements are pretty close to 0.  I find that when I take log(my_array), I get the error "FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in log".  Note that this is after setting seterr(invalid='raise') in numpy intentionally.

How can I deal with this numerical issue?  I'd like to represent vectors corresponding to a probability distribution and their take log without rounding to 0, since then I end up taking log(0) which raises the error.

thanks.

Comment: Probability of zero is a special case, why would you consider it to be the same as non-zero probabilities?  Why not simply filter it out of the data and work with the non-zero only?

Comment: Have you double checked that all the values in the distribution are really positive?  No negative values and no values that are exactly zero?  Really small values should not matter.

Comment: Same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704570/in-python-small-floats-tending-to-zero

Answer (score 3):

You can just drop the tails according to the accuracy you need.

```
eps = 1e-50
array[array<eps]=eps
log(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

What's pretty close to zero ?

```
>>> np.log(0)
-inf
>>> 0.*np.log(0)
nan
>>> np.log(1e-200)
-460.51701859880916
>>> 1e-200*np.log(1e-200)
-4.6051701859880914e-198
```

One solution is to add a small positive number to all probabilities to restrict them to be far enough away from zero.

The second solution is to handle zeros explicitly, for example replace 0.*np.log(0) with zeros in the resulting array, or only include points that have nonzero probability in the probability array

Answer (score 1):

How 'pretty close' to 0 are they? Python seems happy taking log of 10^-very large:

```
>>> log(0.0000000000000000000000000001)
-64.472382603833282
```

Also, why are you taking logs? What do you plan to do with them once you've took them?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing afterwards, you could use a different transform that doesn't explode on zero values like log does.  Perhaps a [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) or something else with a well-defined Jacobian.

If you're just looking to visualize the data, you could always add some tiny value before you take the log.