# Type specific output expected using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I calculated changbtwread column using this code below for multiple type.

```
for v in df['Type'].unique():
    df[f'Changebetweenreadings_{v}'] = df.loc[df['Type'].eq(v), 'Last'].diff()
```

Given

```
  Type     Last  changbtwread_ada  changbtwread_btc  changbtwread_eur
0  ada  3071.56               NaN               NaN               NaN
1  ada  3097.82             26.26               NaN               NaN
2  btc  1000.00               NaN               NaN               NaN
3  ada  2000.00          -1097.82               NaN               NaN
4  btc  3000.00               NaN            2000.0               NaN
5  eur  1000.00               NaN               NaN               NaN
6  eur  1500.00               NaN               NaN             500.0
```

Now that i need to calculate direction column based on these changebtw column.

My output should look like

```
Type    change_dir_ada    change_dir_btc   change_dir_eur   
ada       Nut
ada       Pos
btc                          Nut
ada       Neg
btc                          Nut
eur
eur                                               Pos
```

A quick fix i tried is using this code.

```
df.loc[df.Changebetweenreadings_btceur > 0, 'ChangeDirection_btceur'] = 'Pos' 
df.loc[df.Changebetweenreadings_btceur < 0, 'ChangeDirection_btceur'] = 'Neg' 
df.loc[df.Changebetweenreadings_btceur == 0, 'ChangeDirection_btceur'] = 'Nut'

df.loc[df.Changebetweenreadings_adabtc > 0, 'ChangeDirection_adabtc'] = 'Pos' 
df.loc[df.Changebetweenreadings_adabtc < 0, 'ChangeDirection_adabtc'] = 'Neg' 
df.loc[df.Changebetweenreadings_adabtc == 0, 'ChangeDirection_adabtc'] = 'Nut'
```

But i this is a lot of code and its not a dynamic way of doing i think. 
I expect something like this.

```
for v in df['Type'].unique():
   df[f'Changebetweenreadings_{v}'] #--> Do this calculation above.
```

It doesn't work for these values

```
change        type    dir_ada   dir_btc
-3637.31      ada      
-4E-08        ada       Neg
-3637.31      ada       Nut
3637.8        btc                  Nut
```

In place of Pos it gives random mapping.

Comment: are you looking for `df.groupby('Type')`?

Comment: No, I don't want to group by.

Comment: it would help to know your data (are `Type` and `Changebetweenreadings` one dataframe? why is the length different?). it would also help to know what error you are facing or what exactly you want to achieve. (e.g. why how do you get 2 columns 6 rows from two series of length 5 and 8). We also don't know content of column `'Last'`.

Comment: Hi, Please check the updated question @cripcate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
vals = ['Pos','Neg', 'Nut']
for v in df['Type'].unique():
    df[f'change_dir_{v}'] = df.loc[df['Type'].eq(v), 'Last'].diff()
    df[f'change_dir_{v}'] = np.select([df[f'change_dir_{v}'] > 0, 
                                       df[f'change_dir_{v}'] < 0, 
                                       df[f'change_dir_{v}']== 0], vals, '')


print (df)
  Type     Last change_dir_ada change_dir_btc change_dir_eur
0  ada  3071.56                                             
1  ada  3097.80            Pos                              
2  btc  1000.00                                             
3  ada  2000.00            Neg                              
4  btc  3000.00                           Pos               
5  eur  1000.00                                             
6  eur  1500.00                                          Pos
```

Comment: please check the error i get after trying this code. It works for most cases and after a while it is giving random mapping.

Comment: @KSp - I try simplify solution, but not sure if understand `random mapping`.

Comment: sorry, i mean to say it randomly assigns pos inplace of neg or nut. like it assigns randomly without any logic, i meant :)

Comment: @KSp - hmmm, there are negative too small numbers, so not easy check it.  e.g. `n= -4E-08` and then `print(f'{n:.10f}')`

Comment: But what about the values like -3643.909983 ? because my values start with two digits and end up having more values, even negatives. So, its still assigning it wrongly. I tried your new code.

Comment: @KSp - I think it seems some data problem :(

Comment: I think data related problem.

Comment: @KSp - I think I find it - problem is to small numbers are convertted to `0` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3704570/2901002) in numpy, I think same problem you find in your real data.

Comment: Thats fine but what about the values like -3643.90 why its not accepted as neg value? Any idea? @jezrael

Comment: @KSp - values are floats? If check `df['colname'].dtype` ?

Comment: Are you asking about Last column or change direction column?

Comment: change_dir_btceur        118175 non-null object
change_dir_adabtc        118175 non-null object
Last                     118175 non-null float64

Comment: hmmm, not necessary answer. Because if not numeric, `diff` raise error. So only last possible solution - try  restart your IDE, if still problem, not idea.  Because for me it working nice, so hard to test your problem.

Comment: @KSp - hmmmm, is possible convert `Last` to integer like `df['Last_new'] = df['Last'].mul(10000).astype(int)` and then test solution with `Last_new`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192622/discussion-between-ksp-and-jezrael).